# React native absolute positioning

Tags: css, react-native, layout, css-position, absolute

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
        <View style={{top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'green'}} ></View>
        <View style={{top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'blue'}} ></View>
        <View style={{top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'purple'}} ></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Since I am using absolute positioning, I expected the three squares to be positioned in the very same spot on top of each other. But what I get is this:

[image]

Can I get the three squares to be positioned exactly where I asked them without any auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your parent view is being positioned absolutely but then each child is laid out automatically *within* said parent. You should apply absolute positioning to each element that you need to position.

```
<View>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'green'}} ></View>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'blue'}} ></View>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'purple'}} ></View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you have to make each one of them absolutely positioned.

```
<View>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'green'}} ></View>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'blue'}} ></View>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, width:50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'purple'}} ></View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

you were doing it wrong you need to apply `position:absolute` to each square

Try this:

```
<View>
    <View style={{top: 50, width:50, height: 50, position: 'absolute',backgroundColor:'green'}} ></View>
    <View style={{top: 50, width:50, height: 50,position: 'absolute', backgroundColor:'blue'}} ></View>
    <View style={{top: 50, width:50, height: 50, position: 'absolute',backgroundColor:'purple'}} ></View>
  </View>
```